# this.$el of Vue components always reference the same dom element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

- I have a component “MText”,the main code is as follows :

  `<template>
  <vue-draggable-resizable @click="deleteFun">
  </vue-draggable-resizable>
  </template>
  export default {
  method:{
  deleteFun () {
  this.$el.remove();
  }
  }}`
- and in another file,I have a function like this

  `function createText(){
  let MyComponent =Vue.extend({
  template:"<MText></MText>",
  components:{MText},
  data () {
  return {}
  }})
  return new MyComponent(); }`
- and I have a button,click event bind a function “addText”,like this

  `addText(){
  let text = createText();
  let panel = document.getElementById("palette");
  let tp_dom = document.createElement("div");
  tp_dom.setAttribute("id","id");
  panel.appendChild(tp_dom);
  text.$mount(tp_dom);
  }`
- the quesition is that when I run “addText” twice, the dom “#palette”
  have two “MText” elements,then,I click the second “MText” element,why
  the first “MText” is deleted;“this.$el” always reference the first
  “MText”

Comment: Please update your question to be better understandable

Comment: dynamically insert vue component "MText" twice or thrice,the "MText" bind a click event that can remove it's dom element,no matter i click which one I insert before,it's always remove the first "MText" I insert。means I click the second inserted "MText" ,not it's removed,but the first inserted "MText" is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your problem is, but here's a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/oddswe36/

```js
let i = 0;

// Register your component globally
Vue.component('MText', {
 template: `
   <div @click="removeMe">click to remove me {{ counter }}</div>
  `,
  data() {
   return {
     counter: i++
    }
  },
  methods: {
   removeMe() {
     this.$el.remove()
    }
  }
})

function createText() {
  const MyComponent = Vue.extend({
    template:"<MText></MText>",
  })
  
  return new MyComponent();
}

function addText() {
  const text = createText();
  const panel = document.getElementById("palette");
  const tp_dom = document.createElement("div");
  tp_dom.setAttribute("id","id");
  panel.appendChild(tp_dom);
  text.$mount(tp_dom);
};

addText();
addText();
addText();
addText();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="palette"></div>
```